# How to stop sliding if only one <li> using anythingSlider(jQuery plugin)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm currently using the [anythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) plugin, it works totally fine except when there is only one `<li>`.

The `<li>`s are generated from the database so sometimes there's only one.

However, the anythingSlider plugin still tries to slide through the `<li>`s, it works by sliding back to the first slide. Although this doesn't look great.

Does anybody know of a way of stopping it sliding if there's only one `<li>`?

-- EDIT --

Hi!

Can anybody else help with this? I've tried the solution by Greg and I've also tried:

```
if (banners<1) {
    .anythingSlider({
        startStopped: true,
        buildNavigation: false
        });
    }
```

'banners' is my variable that I'm calling.

And this disables the anythingSlider function altogether.

Help please?!

-- EDIT 2 --

The original code is in the page of the html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var banners=[];

banners[0]="http://image.ebuyer.com/customer/promos/UK/AcerAspire5536.jpg";
//banners[1]="http://image.ebuyer.com/customer/promos/2150/banner.jpg";
//banners[2]="http://image.ebuyer.com/customer/promos/UK/257653_FerrariOne_tb20091026.jpg";
//banners[3]="http://image.ebuyer.com/customer/promos/UK/247038_compaq_images/247038_compaq_incentive_banner20090814.jpg"; //added 03/09/2009
//banners[4]="http://image.ebuyer.com/customer/promos/UK/247858-samsung-tv-comp-tb20090817.jpg"; //added 19/08/2009

var bannerLink=[];

bannerLink[0]="http://www.ebuyer.com/product/173536";
//bannerLink[1]="/special/2150";
//bannerLink[2]="/product/172295";
//bannerLink[3]="/compaq-cash-incentive";
//bannerLink[4]="/special/2101";

var bannerAlt=[];

bannerAlt[0]="Acer Aspire 5536";
//bannerAlt[1]="The X5 range for Asus";
//bannerAlt[2]="Acer Ferrari One Laptop";
//bannerAlt[3]="Buy these three products together and claim £75 cashback";
//bannerAlt[4]="Win a Samsung 46in LCV TV";

</script>
```

It's then being actioned by this file: http://image.ebuyer.com/customer/promos/js/topbanners.js

```
// function to import css and javascript from external locations
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

// importing css and javascript
loadjscssfile("http://static.ebuyer.com/css/slider.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file

// setting the variables
var banner = document.getElementById('tehBanner');
var link = document.getElementById('tehLink');

// this function creates the tracking tags
function tracking (x) {
    if (x.indexOf("?")>=0){x+='&tb='+(i+1);}else{x+='?tb='+(i+1);}
    return x 
    }

// telling the javascript to display all available variables    
for (var i in banners) {
    banner.alt = bannerAlt[i];  
    link.href = tracking(bannerLink[i]);
    banner.src = banners[i];
    document.write('<a href="' + bannerLink[i] + '" class="slide-link">' + '<img src="' + banners[i] + '" id="slide-image" alt="' + bannerAlt[i] + '" /></a>');
    }

// remove the original banner
$ ('a#tehLink').parent().remove();

// hide banners to begin with
$('a.slide-link').hide();

/*
    anythingSlider v1.1

    By Chris Coyier: http://css-tricks.com
    with major improvements by Doug Neiner: http://pixelgraphics.us/
    based on work by Remy Sharp: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/


    To use the navigationFormatter function, you must have a function that
    accepts two paramaters, and returns a string of HTML text.

    index = integer index (1 based);
    panel = jQuery wrapped LI item this tab references
    @return = Must return a string of HTML/Text

    navigationFormatter: function(index, panel){
        return index + " Panel"; // This would have each tab with the text 'X Panel' where X = index
    }
*/

(function($){

    $.anythingSlider = function(el, options){
        // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
        // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
        var base = this;

        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el; 

        // Set up a few defaults
        base.currentPage = 1;
        base.timer = null;
        base.playing = false;

        // Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
        base.$el.data("AnythingSlider", base);

        base.init = function(){
            base.options = $.extend({},$.anythingSlider.defaults, options);

            // Cache existing DOM elements for later 
            base.$wrapper = base.$el.find('> div').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            base.$slider  = base.$wrapper.find('> ul');
            base.$items   = base.$slider.find('> li');
            base.$single  = base.$items.filter(':first');

            // Build the navigation if needed
            if(base.options.buildNavigation) base.buildNavigation();

            // Get the details
            base.singleWidth = base.$single.outerWidth();
            base.pages = base.$items.length;

            // Top and tail the list with 'visible' number of items, top has the last section, and tail has the first
            // This supports the "infinite" scrolling
            base.$items.filter(':first').before(base.$items.filter(':last').clone().addClass('cloned'));
            base.$items.filter(':last' ).after(base.$items.filter(':first').clone().addClass('cloned'));

            // We just added two items, time to re-cache the list
            base.$items = base.$slider.find('> li'); // reselect

            // Setup our forward/backward navigation
            base.buildNextBackButtons();

            // If autoPlay functionality is included, then initialize the settings
            if(base.options.autoPlay) {
                base.playing = !base.options.startStopped; // Sets the playing variable to false if startStopped is true
                base.buildAutoPlay();
            };

            // If pauseOnHover then add hover effects
            if(base.options.pauseOnHover) {
                base.$el.hover(function(){
                    base.clearTimer();
                }, function(){
                    base.startStop(base.playing);
                });
            }

            // If a hash can not be used to trigger the plugin, then go to page 1
            if((base.options.hashTags == true && !base.gotoHash()) || base.options.hashTags == false){
                base.setCurrentPage(1);
            };
        };

        base.gotoPage = function(page, autoplay){
            // When autoplay isn't passed, we stop the timer
            if(autoplay !== true) autoplay = false;
            if(!autoplay) base.startStop(false);

            if(typeof(page) == "undefined" || page == null) {
                page = 1;
                base.setCurrentPage(1);
            };

            // Just check for bounds
            if(page > base.pages + 1) page = base.pages;
            if(page < 0 ) page = 1;

            var dir = page < base.currentPage ? -1 : 1,
                n = Math.abs(base.currentPage - page),
                left = base.singleWidth * dir * n;

            base.$wrapper.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                scrollLeft : '+=' + left
            }, base.options.animationTime, base.options.easing, function () {
                if (page == 0) {
                    base.$wrapper.scrollLeft(base.singleWidth * base.pages);
                    page = base.pages;
                } else if (page > base.pages) {
                    base.$wrapper.scrollLeft(base.singleWidth);
                    // reset back to start position
                    page = 1;
                };
                base.setCurrentPage(page);

            });
        };

        base.setCurrentPage = function(page, move){
            // Set visual
            if(base.options.buildNavigation){
                base.$nav.find('.cur').removeClass('cur');
                $(base.$navLinks[page - 1]).addClass('cur');    
            };

            // Only change left if move does not equal false
            if(move !== false) base.$wrapper.scrollLeft(base.singleWidth * page);

            // Update local variable
            base.currentPage = page;
        };

        base.goForward = function(autoplay){
            if(autoplay !== true) autoplay = false;
            base.gotoPage(base.currentPage + 1, autoplay);
        };

        base.goBack = function(){
            base.gotoPage(base.currentPage - 1);
        };

        // This method tries to find a hash that matches panel-X
        // If found, it tries to find a matching item
        // If that is found as well, then that item starts visible
        base.gotoHash = function(){
            if(/^#?panel-\d+$/.test(window.location.hash)){
                var index = parseInt(window.location.hash.substr(7));
                var $item = base.$items.filter(':eq(' + index + ')');
                if($item.length != 0){
                    base.setCurrentPage(index);
                    return true;
                };
            };
            return false; // A item wasn't found;
        };

        // Creates the numbered navigation links
        base.buildNavigation = function(){
            base.$nav = $("<div id='thumbNav'></div>").appendTo(base.$el);
            base.$items.each(function(i,el){
                var index = i + 1;
                var $a = $("<a href='#'></a>");

                // If a formatter function is present, use it
                if( typeof(base.options.navigationFormatter) == "function"){
                    $a.html(base.options.navigationFormatter(index, $(this)));
                } else {
                    $a.text(index);
                }
                $a.click(function(e){
                    base.gotoPage(index);

                    if (base.options.hashTags)
                        base.setHash('panel-' + index);

                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                base.$nav.append($a);
            });
            base.$navLinks = base.$nav.find('> a');
        };


        // Creates the Forward/Backward buttons
        base.buildNextBackButtons = function(){
            var $forward = $('<a class="arrow forward">&gt;</a>'),
                $back    = $('<a class="arrow back">&lt;</a>');

            // Bind to the forward and back buttons
            $back.click(function(e){
                base.goBack();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $forward.click(function(e){
                base.goForward();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // Append elements to page
            base.$wrapper.after($back).after($forward);
        };

        // Creates the Start/Stop button
        base.buildAutoPlay = function(){

            base.$startStop = $("<a href='#' id='start-stop'></a>").html(base.playing ? base.options.stopText :  base.options.startText);
            base.$el.append(base.$startStop);            
            base.$startStop.click(function(e){
                base.startStop(!base.playing);
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // Use the same setting, but trigger the start;
            base.startStop(base.playing);
        };

        // Handles stopping and playing the slideshow
        // Pass startStop(false) to stop and startStop(true) to play
        base.startStop = function(playing){
            if(playing !== true) playing = false; // Default if not supplied is false

            // Update variable
            base.playing = playing;

            // Toggle playing and text
            base.$startStop.toggleClass("playing", playing).html( playing ? base.options.stopText : base.options.startText );

            if(playing){
                base.clearTimer(); // Just in case this was triggered twice in a row
                base.timer = window.setInterval(function(){
                    base.goForward(true);
                }, base.options.delay);
            } else {
                base.clearTimer();
            };
        };

        base.clearTimer = function(){
            // Clear the timer only if it is set
            if(base.timer) window.clearInterval(base.timer);
        };

        // Taken from AJAXY jquery.history Plugin
        base.setHash = function ( hash ) {
            // Write hash
            if ( typeof window.location.hash !== 'undefined' ) {
                if ( window.location.hash !== hash ) {
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                };
            } else if ( location.hash !== hash ) {
                location.hash = hash;
            };

            // Done
            return hash;
        };
        // <-- End AJAXY code


        // Trigger the initialization
        base.init();
    };


    $.anythingSlider.defaults = {
        easing: "swing",                // Anything other than "linear" or "swing" requires the easing plugin
        autoPlay: true,                 // This turns off the entire FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not
        startStopped: false,            // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
        delay: 3000,                    // How long between slide transitions in AutoPlay mode
        animationTime: 600,             // How long the slide transition takes
        hashTags: true,                 // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
        buildNavigation: true,          // If true, builds and list of anchor links to link to each slide
        pauseOnHover: true,             // If true, and autoPlay is enabled, the show will pause on hover
        startText: "Start",             // Start text
        stopText: "Stop",               // Stop text
        navigationFormatter: null       // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
    };


    $.fn.anythingSlider = function(options){
        if(typeof(options) == "object"){
            return this.each(function(i){           
                (new $.anythingSlider(this, options));

                // This plugin supports multiple instances, but only one can support hash-tag support
                // This disables hash-tags on all items but the first one
                options.hashTags = false;
            }); 
        } else if (typeof(options) == "number") {

            return this.each(function(i){
                var anySlide = $(this).data('AnythingSlider');
                if(anySlide){
                    anySlide.gotoPage(options);
                }
            });
        }
    };


})(jQuery);

// this function wraps the elements in the neccessary tags to work with anything Slider
$ (document).ready(function() {
    $('a.slide-link')
        .wrap('<li class="slide-list-item"></li>');
    $('li.slide-list-item')
        .wrapAll('<ul id="slide-list"></ul>');
    $('ul#slide-list')
        .wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    $('div.wrapper')
        .wrapAll('<div class="anythingSlider internalSlider"></div>');
    $('.anythingSlider')
        .anythingSlider({
            easing: "swing",                // Anything other than "linear" or "swing" requires the easing plugin
            autoPlay: true,                 // This turns off the entire FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not
            startStopped: false,            // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
            delay: 7000,                    // How long between slide transitions in AutoPlay mode
            animationTime: 600,             // How long the slide transition takes
            hashTags: false,                 // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
            buildNavigation: true,          // If true, builds and list of anchor links to link to each slide
            pauseOnHover: true,             // If true, and autoPlay is enabled, the show will pause on hover
            startText: "Start",             // Start text
            stopText: "Stop",               // Stop text
            navigationFormatter: null       // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
        });
    $('a.slide-link').show();
    });
```

It's a bit of a hash job but works fine as long as there's more than one `<li>`

Comment: If you can post up a full example of the code, I can have it fixed for you in about half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// this function wraps the elements in the neccessary tags to work with anything Slider
$ (document).ready(function() {
    $('a.slide-link')
        .wrap('<li class="slide-list-item"></li>');
    $('li.slide-list-item')
        .wrapAll('<ul id="slide-list"></ul>');
    $('ul#slide-list')
        .wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    $('div.wrapper')
        .wrapAll('<div class="anythingSlider internalSlider"></div>');

    if(banners.length > 1){
        autoplayval= true;
    } else {
        autoplayval= false;
    }
    $('.anythingSlider')
        .anythingSlider({
            easing: "swing",                // Anything other than "linear" or "swing" requires the easing plugin
            autoPlay: autoplayval,                 // This turns off the entire FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not
            startStopped: false,            // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
            delay: 7000,                    // How long between slide transitions in AutoPlay mode
            animationTime: 600,             // How long the slide transition takes
            hashTags: false,                 // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
            buildNavigation: true,          // If true, builds and list of anchor links to link to each slide
            pauseOnHover: true,             // If true, and autoPlay is enabled, the show will pause on hover
            startText: "Start",             // Start text
            stopText: "Stop",               // Stop text
            navigationFormatter: null       // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
        });
    $('a.slide-link').show();
});
```

Comment: That's magic ... it was the if(banners.length > 1) bit that I couldn't figure out. I'm still new to jQuery. I've tweaked the end code a bit but essentially it's the same(I removed the autoplayval variable)

I'll add the thanks in the code. :-D

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Changing this

```
$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider({...});
```

to this

```
$('.anythingSlider:has(li:nth-child(2)').anythingSlider({...});
```

should do it

This assumes you don't have nested lists.

Comment: Hi this doesn't work. It disables the function altogether even if there are more than 1 item.

Comment: it's the same as the anything slider ... it's live on this page ... http://www.ebuyer.com/store/Computer/cat/Laptop---PC-Accessories

Comment: Greg just forgot a closing bracket within the selector, did you copy it directly or fix that?

Comment: sorry, just to clarify it should be '.anythingSlider:has(li:nth-child(2))'

Comment: @sanchothefat I tried that initially and it didn't work ... I noticed he was missing the closing bracket myself.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and could only resolve this with a new version of the plugin: **v1.5.3**
URL: https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/downloads

Once you've got the latest version, only change one line:

```
base.setCurrentPage(startPanel, false); // added to trigger events for FX code
```

When I have only one `<li>` the `anythingControls` element's style is `display=none`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like

```
if($([ULELEMENT]).children('li').length > 1){

//Your code

}
```

Something along those lines. If you post your code, I can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This will only activate the slider if more than 1 `<LI>` elements are present:

```
jQuery("#sliderDiv:has(>li:eq(1))").anythingSlider({...})
```

it assumes your HTML structure is like this:

```
<div id="sliderDiv">
  <li>Offer 1</li>
  <li>Offer 2</li>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't work either ... although it doesn't disable the slider like the previous suggestion ... so it must be close to being right!